# pgp_sym_encrypt/pgp_sym_decrypt error handling

Tags: postgresql, encryption

I had been using MySQL as database and had planned to move to postgresql.  I had used aes_encrypt and aes_decrypt functions in MySQL extensively throughout my application.  So whenever the encryption/decrytion fails, MySQL automatically returns 'null'.

I am unsure how to handle the same in postgresql.  Tried using the pgp_sym_encrypt/pgp_sym_decrypt functions.  If the encryption key is wrong, it throws error "Wrong key/corrupt data".  I tried searching for some functions that could capture this error and return 'null' as in MySQL so that I need not modify my code.  I had been searching but could not find one.

Has anybody used any error handling mechanism for individual queries? I had found that error handling can be done for procedures.  But, I had to completely rewrite the entire application for that.

If you could share some details, it would be of great help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you wish to avoid modifying your code and have the functions return `NULL` on error, you can do this by wrapping them in a PL/PgSQL function that uses a `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` block to trap the error.

To do this, first I get the SQLSTATE for the error:

```
regress=# \set VERBOSITY verbose
regress=# SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt('fred','key');
ERROR:  39000: Wrong key or corrupt data
LOCATION:  decrypt_internal, pgp-pgsql.c:607
```

I could use this directly in the error handler, but I prefer to use a symbolic name, so I look up the error name associated with 39000 in [Appendix A - Error codes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html), finding that it's the generic function call error `external_routine_invocation_exception`. Not as specific as we would've liked, but it'll do.

Now a wrapper function is required. Something like this must be defined, with one function for each overloaded signature of `pgp_sym_decrypt` that you wish to support. For the `(bytea,text)` form that returns `text`, for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pgp_sym_decrypt_null_on_err(data bytea, psw text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN pgp_sym_decrypt(data, psw);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN external_routine_invocation_exception THEN
    RAISE DEBUG USING
       MESSAGE = format('Decryption failed: SQLSTATE %s, Msg: %s',
                        SQLSTATE,SQLERRM),
       HINT = 'pgp_sym_encrypt(...) failed; check your key',
       ERRCODE = 'external_routine_invocation_exception';
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I've chosen to preseve the original error in a `DEBUG` level message. Here's a comparison of the original and wrapper, with full message verbosity and debug level output.

Enable debug output to show the `RAISE`. Note that it also shows the *original query text of the `pgp_decrypt_sym` call, including parameters.

```
regress=# SET client_min_messages = DEBUG;
```

New wrapped function still reports the error if detailed logging is enabled, but returns `NULL`:

```
regress=# SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt_null_on_err('redsdfsfdsfd','bobsdf');
LOG:  00000: statement: SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt_null_on_err('redsdfsfdsfd','bobsdf');
LOCATION:  exec_simple_query, postgres.c:860
DEBUG:  39000: Decryption failed: SQLSTATE 39000, Msg: Wrong key or corrupt data
HINT:  pgp_sym_encrypt(...) failed; check your key
LOCATION:  exec_stmt_raise, pl_exec.c:2806
 pgp_sym_decrypt_null_on_err
-----------------------------

(1 row)
```

compared to the original, which fails:

```
regress=# SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt('redsdfsfdsfd','bobsdf');
LOG:  00000: statement: SELECT pgp_sym_decrypt('redsdfsfdsfd','bobsdf');
LOCATION:  exec_simple_query, postgres.c:860
ERROR:  39000: Wrong key or corrupt data
LOCATION:  decrypt_internal, pgp-pgsql.c:607
```

Note that **both forms show the parameters the function was called with when it failed**. The parameters won't be shown if you've used bind parameters ("prepared statements"), but you should still consider your logs to be security critical if you're using in-database encryption.

Personally, I think it's better to do crypto in the app, so the DB never has access to the keys.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have decided to go for implementing a function of this kind as a last resort. Very useful indeed. I am trying to get max out of the in-build pgsql functions. Let me see how best it helps.

Also thanks for your suggestion to do all the crypto in the app..yes  that is how i had already planned to change few critical functionalities in the app. i shall later change everything..

Comment: @user1365983 Good - I don't think this is a very good idea, so I'm glad you're not planning on doing it. Please accept the answer if it was helpful, using the tick under the answer score in the top left.